# rearrange multiple columns based on the indices

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe which contains columns as

> ['ID_slice-0010-EDSR_x2', 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0012-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0012-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0013-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0013-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0014-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0014-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0015-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0015-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0016-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0016-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0017-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0017-EDSR_x2_Y', 'slice-0018-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0018-EDSR_x2_Y', 'ID_slice-0011-EDSR_x2',
> 'ID_slice-0012-EDSR_x2', 'ID_slice-0013-EDSR_x2',
> 'ID_slice-0014-EDSR_x2', 'ID_slice-0015-EDSR_x2',
> 'ID_slice-0016-EDSR_x2', 'ID_slice-0017-EDSR_x2',
> 'ID_slice-0018-EDSR_x2']

as the column starting with ID are at the end it should at specific position.So I want to rerrange it to like this

> ['ID_slice-0010-EDSR_x2','slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X',
> 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0011-EDSR_x2','slice-0011-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0012-EDSR_x2','slice-0012-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0012-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0013-EDSR_x2','slice-0013-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0013-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0014-EDSR_x2','slice-0014-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0014-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0015-EDSR_x2','slice-0015-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0015-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0016-EDSR_x2','slice-0016-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0016-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0017-EDSR_x2','slice-0017-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0017-EDSR_x2_Y',
> 'ID_slice-0018-EDSR_x2','slice-0018-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0018-EDSR_x2_Y']

I tried using the method but it becomes static so I want it using something

```
In [7]: cols = df.columns.tolist()
In [8]: cols
Out[8]: [0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 'mean']

In [12]: cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]

In [13]: cols
Out[13]: ['mean', 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L]
  
In [14]: df = df[cols]
```

This is whart I tried

```
finaldf = finaldf[['ID_slice-0010-EDSR_x2','slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0011-EDSR_x2','slice-0011-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0012-EDSR_x2','slice-0012-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0012-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0013-EDSR_x2','slice-0013-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0013-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0014-EDSR_x2','slice-0014-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0014-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0015-EDSR_x2','slice-0015-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0015-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0016-EDSR_x2','slice-0016-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0016-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0017-EDSR_x2','slice-0017-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0017-EDSR_x2_Y', 
                   'ID_slice-0018-EDSR_x2','slice-0018-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0018-EDSR_x2_Y']]
finaldf.to_csv("id.csv",index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use sorted by lambda for sort by integers created by `split` and also replace last `x2` for `x2_` for correct soring by values after last `_`:

```
import re

new = sorted(cols, key=lambda x:(int(x.split('-')[1]),re.sub('x2$','x2_',x).split('_')[-1]))
print (new[:6])
['ID_slice-0010-EDSR_x2', 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y', 
 'ID_slice-0011-EDSR_x2', 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_Y']
```

Pandas solution create 2 helper columns for sorting:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c': cols})
df['a'] = df['c'].str.split('-').str[1].astype(int)
df['b'] = np.where(df['c'].str.endswith('x2'), 'A', df['c'].str.split('_').str[-1])

df = df.sort_values(['a','b'])
print (df.head(6))
                        c   a  b
0   ID_slice-0010-EDSR_x2  10  A
1    slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X  10  X
2    slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y  10  Y
19  ID_slice-0011-EDSR_x2  11  A
3    slice-0011-EDSR_x2_X  11  X
4    slice-0011-EDSR_x2_Y  11  Y

new = df['c'].tolist()
print (new[:6])
['ID_slice-0010-EDSR_x2', 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0010-EDSR_x2_Y', 
 'ID_slice-0011-EDSR_x2', 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_X', 'slice-0011-EDSR_x2_Y']
```